# How can I make a system to capture a photo without user permission in Android?

Tags: android

I can make a camera which will open after get any message and replay this image by photo in an Android phone. How can I make it without using user permission?

```java
 Intent in = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Every application when is installed shows a list of permissions,
and only can be installed if the user accepts to install, in fact for
security issues you can´t make an application that capture a photo
without user permission...
```

**[Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms)**

> Requests a permission that the application must be granted in order
>   for it to operate correctly. Permissions are granted by the user when
>   the application is installed, not while it's running.

imagine that your question is that application, i think more than one want delete your question! :0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `startActivityForResult` to get the picture returned. As explained  in the documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image for creating the intent, and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive for how to receive the result.